# How to setup an ascii text-only printer in OS X

Tags: macos, drivers, printer

Is it possible to setup a printer equivalent to the Windows 'generic ascii text-only printer' in Mac OS X.

I cannot find anything about it within the current cups drivers docs. But I think there has been one in the early days, isn't it?

The goal is to print to a file with generic ascii only.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can do this with the `lpr` command. For example:

```
echo "Hello world!" | lpr
```

Will print a single page with `Hello world!` written on it. If you have a plain text file named `print-me.txt`, you can also do:

```
lpr < print-me.txt
```

to have `lpr` read from the file and print it out the same way. There are lots of options you can provide to `lpr` to change options: check out `man lpr` for more info. (`lpr` can also print PDF documents!)